# x3::phrase_parse is not expected

Tags: c++, boost, lua, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

I expect to parse Lua syntax through x3,The Complete Syntax of Lua: https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#9

My question is, in this definition, `[auto const expdef=simexp | (simexp>>binop>>simexp) | (unop>>simexp);]`

Why not choose `(simexp>>binop>>simexp)` when it fails。

I have the following results:

**output:**

```xml
<chunk>
  <try>\n        function Lu</try>
  <block>
    <try>\n        function Lu</try>
    <stat>
      <try>\n        function Lu</try>
      <funcname>
        <try> LuaPrint(str)\n     </try>
        <Name>
          <try> LuaPrint(str)\n     </try>
          <success>(str)\n            pr</success>
          <attributes>[L, u, a, P, r, i, n, t]</attributes>
        </Name>
        <Name>
          <try> LuaPrint(str)\n     </try>
          <success>(str)\n            pr</success>
          <attributes>[L, u, a, P, r, i, n, t]</attributes>
        </Name>
        <success>(str)\n            pr</success>
      </funcname>
      <funcbody>
        <try>(str)\n            pr</try>
        <parlist>
          <try>str)\n            pri</try>
          <namelist>
            <try>str)\n            pri</try>
            <Name>
              <try>str)\n            pri</try>
              <success>)\n            print(</success>
              <attributes>[s, t, r]</attributes>
            </Name>
            <success>)\n            print(</success>
          </namelist>
          <success>)\n            print(</success>
        </parlist>
        <block>
          <try>\n            print("</try>
          <stat>
            <try>\n            print("</try>
            <label>
              <try>print("[in lua]:" ..</try>
              <fail/>
            </label>
            <functioncall>
              <try>print("[in lua]:" ..</try>
              <prefixexp>
                <try>print("[in lua]:" ..</try>
                <var>
                  <try>print("[in lua]:" ..</try>
                  <Name>
                    <try>print("[in lua]:" ..</try>
                    <success>("[in lua]:" .. tost</success>
                    <attributes>[p, r, i, n, t]</attributes>
                  </Name>
                  <success>("[in lua]:" .. tost</success>
                </var>
                <success>("[in lua]:" .. tost</success>
              </prefixexp>
              <args>
                <try>("[in lua]:" .. tost</try>
                <explist>
                  <try>"[in lua]:" .. tostr</try>
                  <exp>
                    <try>"[in lua]:" .. tostr</try>
                    <simexp>
                      <try>"[in lua]:" .. tostr</try>
                      <literal_string>
                        <try>"[in lua]:" .. tostr</try>
                        <success> .. tostring(str))\n </success>
                        <attributes>[[, i, n,  , l, u, a, ], :]</attributes>
                      </literal_string>
                      <success> .. tostring(str))\n </success>
                    </simexp>
                    <success> .. tostring(str))\n </success>
                  </exp>
                  <success> .. tostring(str))\n </success>
                </explist>
                <tableconstructor>
                  <try>("[in lua]:" .. tost</try>
                  <fail/>
                </tableconstructor>
                <literal_string>
                  <try>("[in lua]:" .. tost</try>
                  <fail/>
                </literal_string>
                <fail/>
              </args>
              <prefixexp>
                <try>print("[in lua]:" ..</try>
                <var>
                  <try>print("[in lua]:" ..</try>
                  <Name>
                    <try>print("[in lua]:" ..</try>
                    <success>("[in lua]:" .. tost</success>
                    <attributes>[p, r, i, n, t]</attributes>
                  </Name>
                  <success>("[in lua]:" .. tost</success>
                </var>
                <success>("[in lua]:" .. tost</success>
              </prefixexp>
              <fail/>
            </functioncall>
            <varlist>
              <try>print("[in lua]:" ..</try>
              <var>
                <try>print("[in lua]:" ..</try>
                <Name>
                  <try>print("[in lua]:" ..</try>
                  <success>("[in lua]:" .. tost</success>
                  <attributes>[p, r, i, n, t]</attributes>
                </Name>
                <success>("[in lua]:" .. tost</success>
              </var>
              <success>("[in lua]:" .. tost</success>
            </varlist>
            <fail/>
          </stat>
          <retstat>
            <try>("[in lua]:" .. tost</try>
            <fail/>
          </retstat>
          <stat>
            <try>\n            print("</try>
            <label>
              <try>print("[in lua]:" ..</try>
              <fail/>
            </label>
            <functioncall>
              <try>print("[in lua]:" ..</try>
              <prefixexp>
                <try>print("[in lua]:" ..</try>
                <var>
                  <try>print("[in lua]:" ..</try>
                  <Name>
                    <try>print("[in lua]:" ..</try>
                    <success>("[in lua]:" .. tost</success>
                    <attributes>[p, r, i, n, t]</attributes>
                  </Name>
                  <success>("[in lua]:" .. tost</success>
                </var>
                <success>("[in lua]:" .. tost</success>
              </prefixexp>
              <args>
                <try>("[in lua]:" .. tost</try>
                <explist>
                  <try>"[in lua]:" .. tostr</try>
                  <exp>
                    <try>"[in lua]:" .. tostr</try>
                    <simexp>
                      <try>"[in lua]:" .. tostr</try>
                      <literal_string>
                        <try>"[in lua]:" .. tostr</try>
                        <success> .. tostring(str))\n </success>
                        <attributes>[[, i, n,  , l, u, a, ], :]</attributes>
                      </literal_string>
                      <success> .. tostring(str))\n </success>
                    </simexp>
                    <success> .. tostring(str))\n </success>
                  </exp>
                  <success> .. tostring(str))\n </success>
                </explist>
                <tableconstructor>
                  <try>("[in lua]:" .. tost</try>
                  <fail/>
                </tableconstructor>
                <literal_string>
                  <try>("[in lua]:" .. tost</try>
                  <fail/>
                </literal_string>
                <fail/>
              </args>
              <prefixexp>
                <try>print("[in lua]:" ..</try>
                <var>
                  <try>print("[in lua]:" ..</try>
                  <Name>
                    <try>print("[in lua]:" ..</try>
                    <success>("[in lua]:" .. tost</success>
                    <attributes>[p, r, i, n, t]</attributes>
                  </Name>
                  <success>("[in lua]:" .. tost</success>
                </var>
                <success>("[in lua]:" .. tost</success>
              </prefixexp>
              <fail/>
            </functioncall>
            <varlist>
              <try>print("[in lua]:" ..</try>
              <var>
                <try>print("[in lua]:" ..</try>
                <Name>
                  <try>print("[in lua]:" ..</try>
                  <success>("[in lua]:" .. tost</success>
                  <attributes>[p, r, i, n, t]</attributes>
                </Name>
                <success>("[in lua]:" .. tost</success>
              </var>
              <success>("[in lua]:" .. tost</success>
            </varlist>
            <fail/>
          </stat>
          <success>("[in lua]:" .. tost</success>
        </block>
        <fail/>
      </funcbody>
      <fail/>
    </stat>
    <retstat>
      <try>("[in lua]:" .. tost</try>
      <fail/>
    </retstat>
    <stat>
      <try>\n        function Lu</try>
      <funcname>
        <try> LuaPrint(str)\n     </try>
        <Name>
          <try> LuaPrint(str)\n     </try>
          <success>(str)\n            pr</success>
          <attributes>[L, u, a, P, r, i, n, t]</attributes>
        </Name>
        <Name>
          <try> LuaPrint(str)\n     </try>
          <success>(str)\n            pr</success>
          <attributes>[L, u, a, P, r, i, n, t]</attributes>
        </Name>
        <success>(str)\n            pr</success>
      </funcname>
      <funcbody>
        <try>(str)\n            pr</try>
        <parlist>
          <try>str)\n            pri</try>
          <namelist>
            <try>str)\n            pri</try>
            <Name>
              <try>str)\n            pri</try>
              <success>)\n            print(</success>
              <attributes>[s, t, r]</attributes>
            </Name>
            <success>)\n            print(</success>
          </namelist>
          <success>)\n            print(</success>
        </parlist>
        <block>
          <try>\n            print("</try>
          <stat>
            <try>\n            print("</try>
            <label>
              <try>print("[in lua]:" ..</try>
              <fail/>
            </label>
            <functioncall>
              <try>print("[in lua]:" ..</try>
              <prefixexp>
                <try>print("[in lua]:" ..</try>
                <var>
                  <try>print("[in lua]:" ..</try>
                  <Name>
                    <try>print("[in lua]:" ..</try>
                    <success>("[in lua]:" .. tost</success>
                    <attributes>[p, r, i, n, t]</attributes>
                  </Name>
                  <success>("[in lua]:" .. tost</success>
                </var>
                <success>("[in lua]:" .. tost</success>
              </prefixexp>
              <args>
                <try>("[in lua]:" .. tost</try>
                <explist>
                  <try>"[in lua]:" .. tostr</try>
                  <exp>
                    <try>"[in lua]:" .. tostr</try>
                    <simexp>
                      <try>"[in lua]:" .. tostr</try>
                      <literal_string>
                        <try>"[in lua]:" .. tostr</try>
                        <success> .. tostring(str))\n </success>
                        <attributes>[[, i, n,  , l, u, a, ], :]</attributes>
                      </literal_string>
                      <success> .. tostring(str))\n </success>
                    </simexp>
                    <success> .. tostring(str))\n </success>
                  </exp>
                  <success> .. tostring(str))\n </success>
                </explist>
                <tableconstructor>
                  <try>("[in lua]:" .. tost</try>
                  <fail/>
                </tableconstructor>
                <literal_string>
                  <try>("[in lua]:" .. tost</try>
                  <fail/>
                </literal_string>
                <fail/>
              </args>
              <prefixexp>
                <try>print("[in lua]:" ..</try>
                <var>
                  <try>print("[in lua]:" ..</try>
                  <Name>
                    <try>print("[in lua]:" ..</try>
                    <success>("[in lua]:" .. tost</success>
                    <attributes>[p, r, i, n, t]</attributes>
                  </Name>
                  <success>("[in lua]:" .. tost</success>
                </var>
                <success>("[in lua]:" .. tost</success>
              </prefixexp>
              <fail/>
            </functioncall>
            <varlist>
              <try>print("[in lua]:" ..</try>
              <var>
                <try>print("[in lua]:" ..</try>
                <Name>
                  <try>print("[in lua]:" ..</try>
                  <success>("[in lua]:" .. tost</success>
                  <attributes>[p, r, i, n, t]</attributes>
                </Name>
                <success>("[in lua]:" .. tost</success>
              </var>
              <success>("[in lua]:" .. tost</success>
            </varlist>
            <fail/>
          </stat>
          <retstat>
            <try>("[in lua]:" .. tost</try>
            <fail/>
          </retstat>
          <stat>
            <try>\n            print("</try>
            <label>
              <try>print("[in lua]:" ..</try>
              <fail/>
            </label>
            <functioncall>
              <try>print("[in lua]:" ..</try>
              <prefixexp>
                <try>print("[in lua]:" ..</try>
                <var>
                  <try>print("[in lua]:" ..</try>
                  <Name>
                    <try>print("[in lua]:" ..</try>
                    <success>("[in lua]:" .. tost</success>
                    <attributes>[p, r, i, n, t]</attributes>
                  </Name>
                  <success>("[in lua]:" .. tost</success>
                </var>
                <success>("[in lua]:" .. tost</success>
              </prefixexp>
              <args>
                <try>("[in lua]:" .. tost</try>
                <explist>
                  <try>"[in lua]:" .. tostr</try>
                  <exp>
                    <try>"[in lua]:" .. tostr</try>
                    <simexp>
                      <try>"[in lua]:" .. tostr</try>
                      <literal_string>
                        <try>"[in lua]:" .. tostr</try>
                        <success> .. tostring(str))\n </success>
                        <attributes>[[, i, n,  , l, u, a, ], :]</attributes>
                      </literal_string>
                      <success> .. tostring(str))\n </success>
                    </simexp>
                    <success> .. tostring(str))\n </success>
                  </exp>
                  <success> .. tostring(str))\n </success>
                </explist>
                <tableconstructor>
                  <try>("[in lua]:" .. tost</try>
                  <fail/>
                </tableconstructor>
                <literal_string>
                  <try>("[in lua]:" .. tost</try>
                  <fail/>
                </literal_string>
                <fail/>
              </args>
              <prefixexp>
                <try>print("[in lua]:" ..</try>
                <var>
                  <try>print("[in lua]:" ..</try>
                  <Name>
                    <try>print("[in lua]:" ..</try>
                    <success>("[in lua]:" .. tost</success>
                    <attributes>[p, r, i, n, t]</attributes>
                  </Name>
                  <success>("[in lua]:" .. tost</success>
                </var>
                <success>("[in lua]:" .. tost</success>
              </prefixexp>
              <fail/>
            </functioncall>
            <varlist>
              <try>print("[in lua]:" ..</try>
              <var>
                <try>print("[in lua]:" ..</try>
                <Name>
                  <try>print("[in lua]:" ..</try>
                  <success>("[in lua]:" .. tost</success>
                  <attributes>[p, r, i, n, t]</attributes>
                </Name>
                <success>("[in lua]:" .. tost</success>
              </var>
              <success>("[in lua]:" .. tost</success>
            </varlist>
            <fail/>
          </stat>
          <success>("[in lua]:" .. tost</success>
        </block>
        <fail/>
      </funcbody>
      <fail/>
    </stat>
    <success>("[in lua]:" .. tost</success>
  </block>
  <success>("[in lua]:" .. tost</success>
</chunk>
parse fail!
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

**Here is my test code:**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <numeric>
#include <fstream>

#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG 1
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_X3_DEBUG 1

#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3/support/ast/position_tagged.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3/support/ast/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3/support/utility/error_reporting.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3/support/utility/annotate_on_success.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/std_pair.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/io.hpp>
namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

namespace ast {

using unop = x3::unused_type;
using binop = x3::unused_type;
using fieldsep = x3::unused_type;
using field = x3::unused_type;
using fieldlist = x3::unused_type;
using tableconstructor = x3::unused_type;
using parlist = x3::unused_type;
using funcbody = x3::unused_type;
using functiondef = x3::unused_type;
using args = x3::unused_type;
using functioncall = x3::unused_type;
using prefixexp = x3::unused_type;
using exp = x3::unused_type;
using explist = x3::unused_type;
using namelist = x3::unused_type;
using var = x3::unused_type;
using varlist = x3::unused_type;
using funcname = x3::unused_type;
using label = x3::unused_type;
using retstat = x3::unused_type;
using stat = x3::unused_type;
using block = x3::unused_type;
using chunk = x3::unused_type;

using boost::fusion::operator<<;
}

//BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(antgroup::ast::person_attr,f_name,l_name);

namespace parse {

struct x3_base_handle {
    template <typename Iterator, typename Exception, typename Context>
    x3::error_handler_result on_error(Iterator& first, Iterator const& last , Exception const& x, Context const& context){
//        std::string message = std::string("Error! here:") + *x.where() + ", Expecting:" + x.which() ;
//        std::cerr << message << std::endl;
        return x3::error_handler_result::fail;
    }
    template <typename T, typename Iterator, typename Context>
    inline void on_success(Iterator const& first, Iterator const& last, T& ast, Context const& context){
        if((last - first) > 0) {
//            auto value = x3::_val(context);
//            auto where = x3::_where(context);
//            auto attr = x3::_attr(context);
//            auto pass = x3::_pass(context);
//            std::cout << "success:" << std::string(first,last) << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

struct unop_class : x3_base_handle{};
struct binop_class : x3_base_handle{};
struct fieldsep_class : x3_base_handle{};
struct field_class : x3_base_handle{};
struct fieldlist_class : x3_base_handle{};
struct tableconstructor_class : x3_base_handle{};
struct parlist_class : x3_base_handle{};
struct funcbody_class : x3_base_handle{};
struct functiondef_class : x3_base_handle{};
struct args_class : x3_base_handle{};
struct functioncall_class : x3_base_handle{};
struct prefixexp_class : x3_base_handle{};
struct exp_class : x3_base_handle{};
struct explist_class : x3_base_handle{};
struct namelist_class : x3_base_handle{};
struct var_class : x3_base_handle{};
struct varlist_class : x3_base_handle{};
struct funcname_class : x3_base_handle{};
struct label_class : x3_base_handle{};
struct retstat_class : x3_base_handle{};
struct stat_class : x3_base_handle{};
struct block_class : x3_base_handle{};
struct chunk_class : x3_base_handle{};


auto const unop = x3::rule<unop_class,ast::unop>{"unop"};
auto const binop = x3::rule<binop_class,ast::binop>{"binop"};
auto const fieldsep = x3::rule<fieldsep_class,ast::fieldsep>{"fieldsep"};
auto const field = x3::rule<field_class,ast::field>{"field"};
auto const fieldlist = x3::rule<fieldlist_class,ast::fieldlist>{"fieldlist"};
auto const tableconstructor = x3::rule<tableconstructor_class,ast::tableconstructor>{"tableconstructor"};
auto const parlist = x3::rule<parlist_class,ast::parlist>{"parlist"};
auto const funcbody = x3::rule<funcbody_class,ast::funcbody>{"funcbody"};
auto const functiondef = x3::rule<functiondef_class,ast::functiondef>{"functiondef"};
auto const args = x3::rule<args_class,ast::args>{"args"};
auto const functioncall = x3::rule<functioncall_class,ast::functioncall>{"functioncall"};
auto const prefixexp = x3::rule<prefixexp_class,ast::prefixexp>{"prefixexp"};
auto const exp = x3::rule<exp_class,ast::exp>{"exp"};
auto const explist = x3::rule<explist_class,ast::explist>{"explist"};
auto const namelist = x3::rule<namelist_class,ast::namelist>{"namelist"};
auto const var = x3::rule<var_class,ast::var>{"var"};
auto const varlist = x3::rule<varlist_class,ast::varlist>{"varlist"};
auto const funcname = x3::rule<funcname_class,ast::funcname>{"funcname"};
auto const label = x3::rule<label_class,ast::label>{"label"};
auto const retstat = x3::rule<retstat_class,ast::retstat>{"retstat"};
auto const stat = x3::rule<stat_class,ast::stat>{"stat"};
auto const block = x3::rule<block_class,ast::block>{"block"};
auto const chunk = x3::rule<chunk_class,ast::chunk>{"chunk"};


struct literal_string_class : x3_base_handle{};
auto const literal_string = x3::rule<literal_string_class, std::string>{"literal_string"};
auto const literal_string_def = (x3::lexeme['"' >> +(x3::char_ - '"') >> '"']) | (x3::lexeme['\'' >> +(x3::char_ - '\'') >> '\'']);
BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(literal_string);

template <typename Tag>
static auto make_sym(std::initializer_list<char const*> elements) {
    x3::symbols<x3::unused_type> instance;
    for (auto el : elements)
        instance += el;
    return instance;
}

static auto const reserve_keywords = make_sym<struct reserve_keywords_class>({"and","break","do","else","elseif","end","false","for","function","goto","if","in","local","nil","not","or","repeat","return","then","true","until","while"});

struct Name_class : x3_base_handle{};
auto const Name = x3::rule<Name_class,std::string>{"Name"};
auto const Name_def = ((x3::ascii::char_("a-zA-Z") | x3::ascii::char_('_')) >> *(x3::ascii::char_("0-9a-zA-Z") | x3::ascii::char_('_'))) - reserve_keywords;
BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(Name);

struct simexp_class : x3_base_handle{};
auto const simexp = x3::rule<simexp_class>{"simexp"};
auto const simexp_def = x3::lit("nil") | "false" | "true" | x3::uint64 | x3::double_ | literal_string | "..." | functiondef | prefixexp | tableconstructor ;
BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(simexp);


//https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#9
auto const unop_def = x3::ascii::char_('-') | x3::lit("not") | x3::ascii::char_('#') | x3::ascii::char_('~');
auto const binop_def = x3::ascii::char_('+') | x3::ascii::char_('-') | x3::ascii::char_('*') | x3::ascii::char_('/') | x3::lit("//") | x3::ascii::char_('^') | x3::ascii::char_('%') | x3::ascii::char_('&') | x3::ascii::char_('~') | x3::ascii::char_('|') | x3::lit(">>") | x3::lit("<<") | x3::lit("..") | x3::ascii::char_('<') | x3::lit("<=") | x3::ascii::char_('>') | x3::lit(">=") | x3::lit("==") | x3::lit("~=") | x3::lit("and") | x3::lit("or");
auto const fieldsep_def = x3::lit(",") | x3::lit(";");
auto const field_def = ("[" >> exp >> "]" >> "=" >> exp) | (Name >> "=" >> exp) | exp;
auto const fieldlist_def = (field >> *(fieldsep >> field)) | (field >> *(fieldsep >> field) >> fieldsep);
auto const tableconstructor_def = x3::lit("{") >> "}" | x3::lit("{") >> fieldlist >> "}";
auto const parlist_def = namelist | (namelist >> "," >> "...") | "...";
auto const funcbody_def = ("(" > parlist > ")" > block > "end") | (x3::lit("(") > ")" > block > "end");
auto const functiondef_def = "function" >> funcbody;
auto const args_def = ("(" >> explist >> ")") | (x3::lit("(") >> ")") | tableconstructor | literal_string;
auto const functioncall_def = (prefixexp >> args) | (prefixexp >> ":" >> Name >> args);
auto const prefixexp_def = var | functioncall | ("(" > exp > ")");
auto const exp_def = simexp | (simexp >> binop >> simexp) | (unop >> simexp);
auto const explist_def = exp >> *("," >> exp); // exp % ","
auto const namelist_def = Name >> *("," >> Name);
auto const var_def = Name | (prefixexp >> "[" >> exp >> "]") | (prefixexp >> "." >>  Name);
auto const varlist_def = var >> *("," >> var);
auto const funcname_def = (Name >> *("." >> Name) >> ":" >> Name) | (Name >> *("." >> Name));
auto const label_def = "::" >> Name >> "::";
auto const retstat_def = ("return" >> explist >> ";") | ("return" >> explist) | "return" | (x3::lit("return") >> ";");
auto const stat_def = x3::lit(";") | "break" | ("goto" > Name) | ("do" > block > "end") | ("while" > exp > "do" > block > "end") | ("repeat" > block > "until" > exp) | ("if" > exp > "then" > block > *("elseif" > exp > "then" > block) > "else" > block > "end") | ("if" > exp > "then" > block > *("elseif" > exp > "then" > block) > "end") | ("for" > Name > "=" > exp > "," > exp > "do" > block > "end") | ("for" > Name > "=" > exp > "," > exp > "," > exp > "do" > block > "end") | ("for" > namelist > "in" > explist > "do" > block > "end") | ("function" > funcname > funcbody) | (x3::lit("local") > "function" > Name > funcbody) | ("local" > namelist) | ("local" > namelist > "=" > explist) | label | functioncall | (varlist > "=" > explist);
auto block_def = (*(stat) >> retstat) | *(stat);
auto chunk_def = block;


BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(chunk,block,stat,retstat,label,funcname,varlist,var,namelist,explist,exp,prefixexp,functioncall,args,functiondef,funcbody,parlist,tableconstructor,fieldlist,field,fieldsep,binop,unop);

}

//local,nil,true,false,end,then,if,elseif,not,and,or,function


int main(int argc,const char *argv[]) {
    
    std::string lua_src_content = R"(
        function LuaPrint(str)
            print("[in lua]:" .. tostring(str))
        end
    )";
    
    typedef std::string::const_iterator iterator_type;
    iterator_type iter = lua_src_content.begin();
    iterator_type end = lua_src_content.end();
    ast::chunk out;
    bool r = x3::phrase_parse(iter, end, parse::chunk, x3::ascii::space, out);
    if(r && (iter == end)){
        std::cout << "parse success!" << std::endl;
    }else{
        std::cerr << "parse fail!" << std::endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Can correctly parse Lua's syntax.

`x3::phrase_parse` returns true.

`(r && (iter == end))` is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PEG (Parser Expression Grammars) are inherently left-to-right greedy. This means, among other things that left recursion needs to be avoided.

> Why not choose (simexp>>binop>>simexp) when it fails

When what fails? If `simexp` fails, then by definition the second branch fails because it starts with a `simexp`. In the general case, parsers `a|a >> b` will never parse the second branch, because if the `a` in `a >> b` would match, then the first branch had already won.

The logical workaround here seems to rephrase as `a >> b|a` or indeed even `a >> -b` depending on the intent/AST.

### Review

There's a lot in the grammar shown that I think can (and should) be fixed. However, most of it is surrounding AST propagation and you specifically left the code out. You can consider posting (a link to) more complete code at codereview.stackexchange.com if you're interested in feedback.

Comment: Yes, I overlooked the greedy nature of left recursion, and I will eliminate the problem of ATS

The test code is complete